Is this correct? Set a baseline variable for my regression model
Please help me! I am not sure how to set a baseline variable for my regression model. I am trying to predict resale value of a house using the following variables.:
categorical variables
town - 26 of them categorized into 5 regions (prevent overfitting) - 5 dummy variables (Northeast, East, Central, North, West)
flattype - array(['1 ROOM', '2 ROOM', '3 ROOM', '4 ROOM', '5 ROOM', 'EXECUTIVE', 'MULTI-GENERATION] - 6 dummy variables
continuous variables
floor_area sqm - min 31 and max 366.7
remaining lease - converted to months min_lease, max_lease - (495, 1173)
resale price
I have coded the following for my regression model, I did not include north, and flat_type_room_1 in my model - does it automatically set north, and flat_type_room_1 as baseline model?:
# Define the dependent variable (resale price)

Y = new_data_with_dummies['resale_price']

# Define the independent variables by extracting numerical data

independent_columns = [

'floor_area_sqm', 'remaining_lease_months',

'region_West', 'region_East',

'region_Central', 'region_Northeast',

'flat_type_ROOM_2', 'flat_type_ROOM_3', 'flat_type_ROOM_4',

'flat_type_ROOM_5', 'flat_type_EXECUTIVE', 'flat_type_MULTI-GENERATION' #north and flat_type_room_1 not included in the model

]

# Extract the independent variables into a plain NumPy array

X = np.column_stack([new_data_with_dummies[col] for col in independent_columns])

# Add a constant (intercept)

X = sm.add_constant(X)

# Fit the multiple linear regression model with proper variable names

linear_model = sm.OLS(Y, X)

result = linear_model.fit()

# Display the model summary

print(result.summary(xname=['const'] + independent_columns))


The category which you dropped from each variable will be in the constant/reference yes, assuming you have a constant in your model.

This seems to be a question about Python code; such questions are off topic here.
